# Is seeking the help of angels permissible in Islam?

Tags: dua, jinn

Selam Aleykum, 
I have a relative who was born muslim, but does not perform the requirements. Years ago she read a book about communicating with and seeking the aid and advice of angels.  And since then she was involved in weekly meetings with a cult who shares this same interest.

I have explained to her several times that you can only ask help from Allah (subhwtalah), so I think she was committing sin.

Over the years her personality has degraded and she insults and is condescending to those around her.

I think this cult she is involved in is practicing witchcraft, and rather than communicating with angels they are communicating with jinn.

Can some knowledgeable people help me to understand what is going on?  How can I help her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who reads the Qur'an and understands it at a basic level would not make the mistake of calling to anyone other than Allah alone. You should encourage her to read the Qur'an and also reference this verse which disproves this cult's practice:

"*O you mankind, a similitude is struck; so listen to it. Surely the ones whom you invoke apart from Allah will never create a fly, even if they gathered together for (the purpose); and in case a fly should rob them of anything, they would not be able to rescue it from him. Weak (indeed) are the seeker and the sought!*" {Qur'an 22:73}